# Rotation of 3D data in XY plane (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, 3d, rotation

I have a 3D array which contains probability values as a function of spatial position (x and y coordinates). When I plot this array using imagesc or surf, I get an elliptic profile with a maximum. I would like to rotate the data around the point of maximum probability in the XY plane such that the Y axis becomes parallel to the major axis of the ellipse (which I computed using regionprops). I don't want to rotate the image or the surface using imrotate or geometric object rotation, since I need the array containing the rotated data. How could I achieve this if I know the angle of rotation around the Z axis (obtained with regionprops)?

*Edit*: Here is the code I used to rotate my matrix around the centroïd. However, when I plot the result using surf, I get the weirdest result...

```
% Translation and anti-translation matrix
translate = [1 0 0 -centroide(1); 0 1 0 -centroide(2); 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1];
anti_translate = [1 0 0 centroide(1); 0 1 0 centroide(2); 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1];

% Rotation matrix
rotate = [cosd(-orientation) -sind(-orientation) 0 0; sind(-orientation)   cosd(-orientation) 0 0; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1];

% Temporary cell array for data transformation
data_vector = cell(size(RCb,1),size(RCb,2),size(RCb,3));
% Cell array for transformed data storage
transformed_data = cell(size(RCb,3),1);
for i = 1:(size(RCb,3))
    transformed_data{i} = zeros(3, size(RCb,1)*size(RCb,2));
end
for i = 1:size(RCb,3) % temporal dimension
    for j = 1:size(RCb,2) % x dimension 
        for k = 1:size(RCb,1) % y dimension
            % [x y z] vector
            data_vector{k,j,i} = [j,k,RCb(k,j,i),1]';
            % translation
            data_vector{k,j,i} = translate*data_vector{k,j,i};
            % rotation
            data_vector{k,j,i} = rotate*data_vector{k,j,i};
            % anti-translation
            data_vector{k,j,i} = anti_translate*data_vector{k,j,i};
            data_vector{k,j,i} = data_vector{k,j,i}(1:3);
            transformed_data{i}(:,((j-1)*size(RCb,1)+k)) = data_vector{k,j,i};
        end
    end
end

%%%% Test %%%% : image at 100 ms
figure,
imagesc(transformed_data{100}(2,:),transformed_data{100}(1,:),transformed_data{100}(3,:));
```

I get this image:[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you add the elliptic profile image to your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `rotz` for Rotation matrix for rotations around z-axis , check the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/rotz.html).

---

Othewise, you can multiply your matrix with the following matrix `R` with the rotation angle γ :

[image]

Be careful, the function `cos` and `sin` in Matlab are radian based. You can use for degree `cosd`.